# Increment value when it is exist using php

Tags: php, laravel

We have import in our module where the import file has number column. In create the number is auto generated(we get the last number of the specific company then + 1)

**For example:**

```
IMPORT FILE
Number: 4
Number 3
Number 2
```

Then clicked the submit button.

**Existing Data/Record**

```
Number: 1
```

When I created new record then saved, the number should be 4 not two. Below is what I've done so far.

**Controller**

```
//check if number exists
$check_if_exists                =   GlobalModel::checkIfNumberExists($data['table'], $data['number'],$data['tag_column'],$data['tag_value']);
while($check_if_exists <= 0){
    $data['number']         = $data['number'] + 1;
}
```

Question: What I want is, I want to continuous increment the number until the number does not exist anymore.

Comment: Your while loop never ends, you need to check if the number exists inside your while loop, so the value of $check_if_exists changes.

Comment: Thanks man ! @GertB.